# How to change Views inside a Fragment from an onActivityResult that is inside another Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, view, onactivityresult

This my look like a duplicated Question , but i have already tried some of the possible solutions given in other questions, after some time i decided that it would be best for me to make a new one.
I am using Kotlin to make an Activity on Android that i use to host a Navigation Drawer and inside that activity there is a fragment with some buttons , when i click on the buttons i initiate a Scan for QrCodes

```
CamaraQrIntegrator = IntentIntegrator(activity!!)
CamaraQrIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
CamaraQrIntegrator.setPrompt("QrCodes")
CamaraQrIntegrator.setCameraId(0)
CamaraQrIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(false)
CamaraQrIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(false)
CamaraQrIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false)
CamaraQrIntegrator.initiateScan()
```

Because ZXing requires me using the parent activity for the IntentIntegrator the onActivityResult is on an Activity instead of the Fragment i am using

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
/// I Try to access a progressbar inside the framgent 
}
```

This makes it so i cannot access any of the views inside the fragment , all return null when tried to called directly with with FindViewById , making a function inside the fragment code to access a view that was initialized after onCreateView, when i try to access the view it tells me the progressbar is null

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
publicView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_principal, container, false)
 progressBar = publicView!!.findViewById(R.id.progressBarPrincipal)
return publicView
}
fun setProgressBarVisible(){
progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
fun setProgressBarGone(){
progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

when i access setProgressBarGone() on the activity it tells me lateinit ProgressBar has not been initializated , althought the fragment has not been destroyed and the progress bar was indeed initializated on OnCreateView.

```
val MainFragment:Fragment = MainFragment()
val fragment = MainFragment().setProgressBarVisible()
```

I have tried making the view on the fragment public, but still is returned as null , i have tried to make the progressbar public and still it is null for the activity, and this is not only happens when onActivity Result at any point i try to access a View in the fragment is return as null.

I don't know what to do  , any help would be nice , please i really feel like thinking something from the beggining so , i would really appreciate new solutions over fixing , what i have. Still anything would be of help for me at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Took a fragment insance while you create that Fragment object and on the onActivityResult access fragment method using craeted insatnace.

Comment: YourFragment yourFragment = new YourFragment();

onActivityResult{
    yourFragment .fragmentMethod();
}